# Logitech MX Keys Wireless Keyboard not working on USB in BIOS and bootloader

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, bios, bootloader

I have purchased Logitech MX Keys keyboard, it works well both on Linux, Windows and Mac but there is one problem. I have a multiple operating systems installed on my computer and when I boot up my computer I am prompted with a Bootloader that asks me to select an operating system to boot. Before I power up my compuer I connect my keyboard with a USB cable but the keyboard does not work. Obviously, I can't access BIOS as well, even though my keyboard is connected with a USB cable. I have another keyboard Apple Magic keyboard, which has a USB as well and when I connect it it works fine in bootloader and BIOS. It is weird that the USB is meant only to charge the keyboard and cannot be used to actually type on the keyboard. Is this expected?

Comment: It's a wireless keyboard, not a USB keyboard.  You could try reading the documentation :-)

Comment: My Aplle Magic Keyboard is a wireless keyboard as well but it does work in bootloader and BIOS on USB.

Answer (score 1):

The
[Logitech MX Keys keyboard documentation](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/mx-keys-wireless-keyboard.html)
specifically says that USB is used for recharging only.

I agree that a $119.99 keyboard should be able to do more than that.

I suggest returning this keyboard and buying another one that does what
you want.

Comment: It does more than that but only with the dongle. Connected by Bluetooth it can't because neither BIOS/UEFI nor Grub support Bluetooth peripherals. It would need a Bluetooth stack that exists only when the OS is loaded.

Comment: Guess what, I've plugged in the dongle included in the set and found out that the keyboard works without a cable in bootloader and BIOS. I'm shocked!!!

Comment: Yes, so it seems that my answer was correct - this keyboard does not function as a USB keyboard.

Comment: @harrymc Not entirely correct. The devices works in two modes: Via Logitech's proprietary wireless dongle (that the OP must use for UEFI/BIOS or Grub) and Bluetooth (always require and OS and the Bluetooth stack). A complete answer, as suggested in the first comment, must include this detail.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: The post was about using the USB cable, not about wireless or Bluetooth. The question about USB was "Is this expected?". My answer of "Yes" was correct. Nobody asked to explain any other functionality of this keyboard. But have it your way.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting the receiver it works both in bootloader and BIOS. I didn't expect it would work on the receiver so that's why I posted this question. Obviously, this meets my expectations so I don't need to plug the cable in order to use the keyboard in bootloader and BIOS. I can just use it wirelessly. I wasn't aware that using wireless usb receiver enables you to use the keyboard in BIOS and bootloader.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. It should be clear now.

Comment: The answer is very much incorrect actually. Your keyboard's specifications clearly mention *Connect via the **included Unifying USB Receiver** or Bluetooth*. One OR the other. The Bluetooth option *always* require an OS with Bluetooth stack to work therefore it cannot possibly work that way in UEFI/BIOS or even at the Grub menu. There's nothing "miraculous" in using a (proprietary) wireless dongle which, for all intended purposes, is "seen" by he PC like any other wired peripheral. Bluetooth has nothing in common with the wireless technology used by the Logitech dongle.

Comment: So you are picky about the word "miraculously"? I removed it now. Please upvote.

Comment: *Please upvote* You must be joking, right? Or still joking because a joke is what the  "answer" is, with or without that word. Next time try reading the user's manual first.

Comment: Well, I don't want to argue with you but you are simply not right. If you add the keayboard on Windows using LG Optiosn software then you can use it in BIOS/UEFI. That's how the Unifing Receiver works.

Comment: I found out after connecting my keyboard via Bloetooth that theUnifying receiver was no more working. I actually to fireup the Solaar program from Logitech (under Linux) to actually get it connected back after performing a scan which overwrote the BT settings of the keyboard. It's too bad that it cannot have both received AND BT available at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I found out after contacting Logitech that any of the three "slots" can be a Unifying receiver or a Bluetooth connection. I currently have my keyboard in receiver mode, while pressing the  key for the second keyboard will stiwtch me to Bluetooth for my work laptop. Press the key for the first keyboard and I am back on the unifying receiver it was paired with.